# Reenable an Angular mat-select field after disabling it

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I have a mat-select field on a form that is used for 2 purposes. First, it can be used to select to include specific values in a data element when searching for records. Second, once a record is found is displays the value of the data element in read-only mode.

When the form is first opened it is in query mode and a function is run to enable/disable the field based on the. This function runs correctly when the form is first displayed.  After the user submits their query the same function is called to disable the field, this also runs correctly. The user then has the ability to set the form back to it's initial state to enter different query parameters, the same function is called.  This time while the mat-input fields are all re-enabled, the mat-select stays disabled.

Here is the HTML for the mat-select field and one mat-input field:

```
<td class="dataLabel" style="width: 40px;">
    Status:
</td>
<td style="width: 100px;" colspan="2">
    <mat-form-field appearance="fill" style="width: 95px;">
        <!-- <input matInput type="text" formControlName="status"/> -->
        <mat-select #status name="status" formControlName="status">
            <mat-option value="MANUAL" >MANUAL</mat-option>
            <mat-option value="UPDATE" >UPDATE</mat-option>
            <mat-option value="DELETE" >DELETE</mat-option>
            <mat-option value="NEW" >NEW</mat-option>
            <mat-option value="TEST" >TEST</mat-option>
        </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>
</td>
<td class="dataLabel" style="width: 100px;">
    Flight Critical:
</td>
<td style="width: 65px;">
    <mat-form-field appearance="fill" style="width: 60px;">
        <input matInput type="text" formControlName="fltCrit"/>
    </mat-form-field>
</td>
```

And here is a partial snippet of the .ts file that enables/disables the fields:

```
  updateQueryFields(){
    console.log("Qmode:", this.qmode)
    if(this.qmode === true){
      console.log("inside qmode === true")
      {...}
      //this.eclForm.controls.status.enable();
      this.eclForm.controls["status"].enable();  
      this.eclForm.controls.fltCrit.disable(); 
      {...}
    } else { 
      console.log("Getting ready to display data")
      {...}
      this.eclForm.controls.status.disable(); 
      this.eclForm.controls.fltCrit.disable(); 
      {...}
    }
  }
```

I asked another member of my team about this and he is as stumped  by this as I am.

He suggested turning the select into an ngModel, but when I tired that I was receiving this error:

Cannot assign value "$event" to template variable "status". Template variables are read-only.

Is there a way I can consistently enable/disable this mat-select?

Comment: Please provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), there is not enough code to be able to reproduce the issue.

Comment: I am trying to create an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), but it is taking some time to remove it from the larger application.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you need to force the form to update after disabling and enabling the fields. You can do that by manually calling `updateValueAndValidity` after disabling and enabling the fields. BTW I like to use `get` when accessing form controls, looks cleaner in my opinion. So try:

```
updateQueryFields(){
  if (this.qmode === true) {
    // ...
    this.eclForm.get('status').enable();
    this.eclForm.get('fltCrit').disable();
  } else { 
    this.eclForm.get('status').disable();
    this.eclForm.get('fltCrit').enable();
    // ...
  }
  this.eclForm.get('status').updateValueAndValidity();
  this.eclForm.get('fltCrit').updateValueAndValidity();
}
```